# Converting String(passed from objc) to Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, objective-c, ios5, split

I am passing a string from objective C to javascript in this way -

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10",@"9",@"8", nil];
string = [[array valueForKey:@"description"] componentsJoinedByString:@","];

[graphView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"methodName2([%@])", string]];
```

and in my javascript I am trying to convert the string into an array by -

```
function methodName2(val)
            {
                var b = val;
                var temp = new Array();
                temp = b.split(',');

                alert(temp);
            }
```

The way I am using to convert does not seem to work. I am wondering if this is because there is a mismatch in the way the javascript understands the "string" being sent to it?

It would be great if someone could help me out with this.

Comment: Why dont yo alert val at the start of the function and see how the string is formatted

Comment: I did that at first and the output came out like `10,9,8`.. at that point I was not able to figure out what format it was.. but like how @ArtFeel says, `val` is already an array

Comment: Oh yes, I understand what is happening now. you objective C is basically calling `methodName2([10,9,8])` which is how you create an array in javascript (the param part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`val` is already an array, you don't need to split it.

Comment: that.. is .. awesome!! I did not know that.. just tested it out and it is that way!! thanks a lot!! would you be able to tell me why it gets stored as an array?

Comment: var array = [10, 9, 8];
    var string = "10, 9, 8";
So, as you call this function like this: `methodName2([10,9,8])`, you send an array in it.